# tomcat wait a few seconds in stop deploy start process necessary?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, wait

In the deployment of application onto tomcat, is it necessary to wait 30 seconds between stop and start?
    i.e.
    stop server => deploy code => start server
    v.s.
    stop server => wait 30s => deploy code => start server
If the waiting time is necessary, why? How long should we wait at least?

Thank you

Comment: No, it's not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until tomcat is definitely stopped - some take the shortcut and just assume that it always stopped in 15 seconds, they add a bit of margin and wait for twice the time before restarting. This will fall on its face when tomcat, any time in the future, doesn't stop in that time - either because of a misbehaving program or just because shutdown time crept up without you adjusting the wait interval.

Just wait until the process is stopped (all the unix start/stop scripts typically remember a pid, a process id, for precisely this reason) and you can immediately start again. Or take the risk and use the shortcut of a fixed time to wait.

Make sure that the decision for the shortcut can't be traced to you (or me, for that matter - because I'd advise against it) ;)